# Tab content 'sticking' when clicked fast?

Tags: jquery, tabs

http://jsfiddle.net/RwPps/25/ -the script

Hi guys, just a quick question (I feel bad for asking although I'm really stuck). The issue with the tabs that I'm using here is that if you spam each tab really quick you can end up with content staying on the same tab when viewing the next, I think I need to add some kind of stop to prevent the script from been spammed repeatably,

Anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this?

Thanks

Phil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.stopImmediatePropagation`, so the click event doesn't bubble. 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RwPps/27/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RwPps/26/

The only thing I've done, is to add a `.stop()` before your `.fadeIn()`. I think the issue (as you may already have guessed), is that the animation doesn't get a chance to complete, before the next event is fire.